# Python BoxPlot Error - 'Series' object has no attribute 'boxplot'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a boxplot and I'm running into this error - 'Series' object has no attribute 'boxplot'

Here is my current code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.gca()
frame['ArrDelay'].boxplot(ax = ax)
ax.set_title('BoxPlot of ArrDelay')
ax.set_xlabel('ArrDelay')
ax.set_ylabel('Delay Time')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Pass the column name as a list instead of a string to access the column as a DataFrame (i.e., use double brackets): `frame[['ArrDelay']].boxplot(ax=ax)`

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using a pandas DataFrame

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.gca()
frame.boxplot(column='ArrDelay', ax=ax)
# frame['ArrDelay'].plot.box(ax=ax) # Alternative
ax.set_title('BoxPlot of ArrDelay')
ax.set_xlabel('ArrDelay')
ax.set_ylabel('Delay Time')
```